# Highchart not show line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem about highstock (highchart) , as you can see the line between 2 data is not showing, but the data is there.
[image]

[image]

JS:

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.setOptions({
});
// create the chart when all data is loaded
createChart = function (seriesOptions) {

    $('#dashboardDetailNoa').highcharts('StockChart', {

        series: seriesOptions
    });
};

$.getJSON(BASE_URL + '/dashboard/ajaxchart/chart', function (data) {
    createChart(data);
});
});
```

JSON return value

```
    [{
    "name": "AX",
    "color": "#92489d",
    "data": [[1421686800000,
    10]]
},
{
    "name": "BY",
    "color": "#ad76b6",
    "data": [[1421686800000,
    0]]
},
{
    "name": "AX",
    "color": "#92489d",
    "data": [[1421773200000,
    1]]
},
{
    "name": "BY",
    "color": "#ad76b6",
    "data": [[1421773200000,
    0]]
},
{
    "name": "AX",
    "color": "#92489d",
    "data": [[1421859600000,
    1]]
},
{
    "name": "BY",
    "color": "#ad76b6",
    "data": [[1421859600000,
    0]]
},
{
    "name": "AX",
    "color": "#92489d",
    "data": [[1421946000000,
    1]]
},
{
    "name": "BY",
    "color": "#ad76b6",
    "data": [[1421946000000,
    0]]
}]
```

And this is javascript that i load in my page

```
jquery-2.1.1.min.js
bootstrap.min.js
highstock.js
myChart.js
```

Anyone can tell me what I must do? I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer . The problem is JSON

correct JSON structure is like this

```
[{
    "name": "AX",
    "color": null,
    "data": [
    [1420045200000,1001],
    [1420131600000,1002],
    [1420218000000,1003],
    ]
},
...........
]
```